# Animation re-runs for every item when using unshift to add the new item instead of push

Tags: angular

I'm using the new animations for angular2 which got released with the RC2 version, it works great except for a rather huge detail.

I'm looping from an array of messages, or notifications as I call them, but rather than pushing to the array I'm using `unshift(message)` to add it at the first index so that it shows first rather than last. It also helps when removing the items due to index issues.

Now, when I add a new item with `unshift`, since the entire array has to update with the correct indexes, all the items re-runs their animation. This seems like a bug to me but perhaps there is something I'm missing?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'notifications',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/notifications/notifications.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './app/assets/scripts/modules/notifications/notifications.component.css',
    './app/assets/styles/angular2-library.css'
  ],
  inputs: [
    'type',
    'position'
  ],
  animations: [
    trigger('notiState', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)',
        opacity: '1',
        visibility: 'visible'
      })),
      transition('void => in', [
        animate('600ms ease', keyframes([
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: '0', offset: 0}),
          style({transform: 'translateX(-40px)', opacity: '1', offset: 0.3}),
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: '1', offset: 1})
        ]))
      ]),
      transition('in => void', [
        animate('300ms ease-out', keyframes([
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: '1', offset: 0}),
          style({transform: 'translateX(-40px)', opacity: '1', offset: 0.7}),
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: '0', offset: 1})
        ]))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

export class NotificationsComponent {
  public notifications: string[] = [];

  constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService, private _notificationsApi: NotificationsApiService) {
    this.ns = _globals.ns;

    _notificationsApi.newNotification$.subscribe(
      notification => {

        this.notifications.unshift(notification);

        setTimeout(() => {

          //This appears to be working now when we're unshifting and then popping instead of pushing and popping
          for (let existingNotification of this.notifications) {

            if (existingNotification.id === notification.id) {
              this.notifications.pop();
            }
          }
        }, 2000);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very yucky indeed. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7239 Might shed some light and it seems that it's a high priority fix at the moment!

Comment: @MaxAlexander Great to hear, thanks!

Comment: @MaxAlexander Looks like this has been merged now :)